# Deserialize a null to DateTime type failed in Symfony WebTestCase

Tags: php, symfony, php-8.1

The sample codes are based on Symfony 6 and PHP 8.1.

I have written a test to verify the RESTful API endpoint */posts/{id}*.

```php
$client->jsonRequest('GET', $url);

$getByIdResponse = $client->getResponse();
echo("json response:::" . $getByIdResponse->getContent());
```

The JSON response output is like this.

```json
{
  "id": "1ec8b1bc-7385-649e-b0ce-d762d4b219cb",
  "title": "test title",
  "content": "test content",
  "status": "DRAFT",
  "createdAt": "2022-02-11T09:19:56+00:00",
  "publishedAt": null,
  "tags": [],
  "comments": []
}
```

Note, the `publishedAt` in the response JSON is a `null`.

I tried to use the `serializer` component to deserialize the response content into a `Post` object.

```php
$getData = $this->getContainer()->get('serializer')->deserialize($getByIdResponse->getContent(), Post::class, "json");
```

When running the test, I get the following exception like this.

```sh
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotNormalizableValueException : 
Failed to denormalize attribute "publishedAt" value for class "App\Entity\Post": 
Expected argument of type "DateTime", "null" given at property path "publishedAt".
```

The [sample codes](https://github.com/hantsy/symfony-sample/blob/enum/rest-sample/tests/Controller/PostControllerTest.php#L63-L70) is available on my Github account. The [`publishedAt` of `Post`](https://github.com/hantsy/symfony-sample/blob/enum/rest-sample/src/Entity/Post.php#L43) is a `DateTime|null` mixed type.

1. What confused me is the default serialized result can not be deserialized using the same `Serializer` component.
2. If possible to configure the `Serializer` component **globally** to skip `null` value and empty value(string, arrays and collections) like Jackson in the Java world when serializing an object into a JSON string.

Comment: Just hit this issue, did you find a solution?